# Need help understanding bond yield outliers

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, yield

I was looking at bond yields on [Fidelity](https://fixedincome.fidelity.com/ftgw/fi/FILanding#tbcurrent-yields%7Chighest-yield) and noticed a few outliers.

The tables below show the 'Highest' and 'Median' yields.

Note the outliers - Agency/GSE 10yr and Corp AAA 2yr - where the highest yields are 1.01 and 2.57 points higher respectively. Looking further the outliers appear to be

- Federal Farm Credits Bond : FEDERAL FARM CR BKS BOND 4.70000% 06/29/2032
- PEFCO: PRIVATE EXPT FDG CORP NOTE 2.45000% 07/15/2024

I assume the higher yield implies higher credit risk. Is that correct? Any idea why that would be? Why would credit risk be higher for only the 10yr period and not for 5yr or 20yr periods? Is there another explanation?

[image: Bond and CD yields - Highest/Median/Diff]

Comment: The "median" looks like the outlier in your summary table, not the one bond. I don't have a Fidelity account so I can't validate it but it seems very odd to have such a drop in the median yield for that tenor.

Comment: It looks like the callable bonds might be the ones with higher yield.